# KDevelop4 : Setting up a project using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, project-setup, kdevelop4

I am using Kdevelop4, and would like to use a default CMake c++ project.

My plan is to partition my application into programs, several shared libraries, and I would like to have a separate project building unit tests (I am planing to use google test).

I have several questions :

1. How to modify default cmake file in order to get a shared library, and not an executable file?
2. How to integrate google testing framework with cmake?

The default CMakeLists.txt produced by KDevelop4 looks something like this :

```
project(kdevbook)

add_executable(kdevbook main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For shared library:

```
add_library(kdevbooklib SHARED source.cpp)
```

[More info.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aadd_library)

2) [Link.](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/Proposals%3aIncreasing_ITK_Code_Coverage#Google_Test)

**Update:**

Root CMakeList.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6.0)

PROJECT(MyGreatProject)

SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${MyGreatProject_BINARY_DIR}/bin CACHE PATH
  "Single output directory for building all libraries.")
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${MyGreatProject_BINARY_DIR}/bin CACHE PATH
  "Single output directory for building all executables.")
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(MyGreatProjectLib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(MyGreatProjectBin)
```

Libs MyGreatProjectLib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(MyGreatProjectLib)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(MyGreatProjectLib SHARED source.cpp)
```

Bin MyGreatProjectBin/CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(MyGreatProjectBin)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${MyGreatProjectLib_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(MyGreatProjectBin main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyGreatProjectBin MyGreatProjectLib)
```

Comment: Just one more question. If I have 3 projects : 1st for the library, 2nd for unit test,3rd for executable, how do I make dependencies? I want the 2nd and 3rd to depend on the 1st. by the way, thanks for the answer

Comment: Is it possible to add such dependencies to cmake at all?

Comment: Yes: see the modified answer.